# Does Xenoblade 3 support controller rumble?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Does Xenoblade Chronicles 3 support controller rumble? I've been playing with [a controller that doesn't have rumble](https://stores.horiusa.com/switch-split-pad-pro-black/) and want to know if I should consider switching.